# Angular - Import both BrowserAnimationsModule and NoopAnimationsModule and decide what to use at runtime (using AOT)

Tags: angular, typescript, jit, aot

The problem is:

I want to import the NoopAnimationsModule only when I'm on an IE.
In my app.module's imports array I have something like:

```
imports: [AppConfig.IS_IE ? NoopAnimationsModule : BrowserAnimationsModule, .... ]
```

This works during the development but not in the production.
I guess it has to do about the AOT compilation when the import gets place before the code
reaches the browser.

I came to the conclusion that I have to import both of them and configure something the during the runtime in order to decide which module's providers should I use.

Keep in mind that both of these modules provide the same services but with differences in order to change the way Angular handles the animation.

Is there a way to implement this idea?

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting. You are right though that aot used to prevent this, <strike>but as far as I know, with ivy, it should already be possible to do it your way, but I'm not sure</strike>.

<sub>Just tested and you are right, with a dynamic value like that, it doesn't work yet</sub>

If you have at least angular 9 you can do the following:

So I assume your `AppConfig.IS_IE` gets set before the animation module is imported. Looking at the source code I believe you could do something like this by creating a custom animations module. This uses a special property `ɵinj`, which is not part of the public API, so it's subject to change:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [BrowserModule],
})
export class ConfigAnimationsModule {
  static forRoot(isIE: boolean) {
    return {
      ngModule: ConfigAnimationsModule,
      providers: isIE
        ? NoopAnimationsModule.ɵinj.providers
        : BrowserAnimationsModule.ɵinj.providers
    };
  }
}
```

which you can then import:

```
imports: [
  ConfigAnimationsModule.forRoot(AppConfig.IS_IE),
  //...
]
```

---

For angular version <= 8 you can use the private property `ngInjectorDef`. Untested though, so your mileage may vary:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [BrowserModule],
})
export class ConfigAnimationsModule {
  static forRoot(isIE: boolean) {
    return {
      ngModule: ConfigAnimationsModule,
      providers: isIE
        ? NoopAnimationsModule['ngInjectorDef'].providers
        : BrowserAnimationsModule['ngInjectorDef'].providers
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: it's still not working. It still imports only NoopAnimationsModule. And that's because the appConfig.IS_IE variable maybe is being initialized before the code reaches the browser. In a few words AppConfig.IS_IE =  window.navigator.userAgent.search(/(?:Edge|MSIE|Trident\/.*; rv:)/) > -1;

You can say that I can use only this condition. Yeah sure but this condition takes place before the code reaches the browser

Comment: @AlexRasidakis I've updated my answer. I've tested it locally with a `Math.random()` value to conditionally on runtime load either one of the modules. It seems to work :). Be aware though that it might not be angular upgrade proof. Nevertheless, I feel like this should be part of core angular, because IE is not very fast with animations

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and your time. But I'm using Angular 7. einj is not recognized. Any alternative on that??

Comment: @AlexRasidakis I've updated my answer again which will work for angular 8, so I guess it will also work for angular 7

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: @AlexRasidakis really? I tested it in stackblitz. Are you getting any error?